# Laravel 5 Sanitizing Required Field Behavior

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to sanitize the user input in my application following [this article](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/03/31/sanitizing-input-using-laravel-5-form-requests/)

Below is my request

```
class TestRequest extends Request
{

   public function authorize()
   {
      return true;
   }

   public function rules()
   {
       $this->sanitize();

      return [
          'title'=>'required|max:100'

      ];
   }

   public function sanitize()
   {

      $input = $this->all();
      if(!empty($input))
      {
        $input['title'] = trim(strip_tags($input['title']));
        $this->replace($input); 

      }

    }
}
```

Tough the title is required field, if I try to put `<h1></h1>` as input in the title field, as per the logic in `sanitize()` function the tags are stripped away, but an empty string is saved in the database. The required field validation in the rules in not taking any effect.

How to handle this?

**Update:**

Below is the controller method for saving the request.

```
public function save(TestRequest $request)
{
   $input = $request->all();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Show related controller method please.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin controller method added..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option is to use merge() instead of replace() in your code, i.e.:

```
$this->merge( ['title' => trim(strip_tags($input['title']))] );
```

Second option is to override the all() function, i.e.:

```
public function all()
{
    $input = parent::all();
    if( !empty($input) )
    {
        $input['title'] = trim(strip_tags($input['title']));
    }
    return $input;
}
```

In the last code example you dont have to use the sanitize() function.

Comment: the merge option didn't work. Second option worked. Could you please elaborate how to handle cleaning the input in case option one, two is not used along with the sanitize method (option 3) ?

Comment: I used option one in the past, I dont remember exact Laravel version. Now, with Laravel 5.4, I usually override validationData() making it public, but that is another long story. In laravel till now there is not an accepted solution for sanitizing input (its a controversial subject). So till you know what you are doing (overriding the all() function is not so advisable), it is fine.

Comment: For the sake of completeness there are two middlewares that transform input, but they are global not per Request. \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings and \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull

Comment: thanks .. I will stick with the all() function for now.. :)